# Haskell: typeclass deriving from other typeclass

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a typeclass for entities being kept in database. Some simplified example may look like this:

```
class Persistent a where
    fetch :: Int -> IO (Maybe a)
    store :: a -> IO Bool
```

Now I found that for `store` I may need to know the type of entity, so it should be also `Typeable`.

Is there some way to tell that all `Persistent` entities are `Typeable` without adding `deriving (Typeable)` to every specific `data` clause? E.g. like this:

```
class Persistent a deriving (Typeable) where
    fetch :: Int -> IO (Maybe a)
    store :: a -> IO Bool
```

Comment: Well `deriving` is actually only automatically generting an instance. But you can write `class Typeable a => Persistent a where ...`.

Comment: No, this is not possible. In `class Persistent a`, `a` doesn't have to represent a *data type declaration*. It's just a type. For example you can add a `Persistent` instance to `Maybe Integer`. So it doesn't make much sense to talk about "adding a `deriving Typeable` clause to all `a`s that happen to be `Persistent`" --- you cannot say `data Maybe Integer deriving Typeable` or anything like that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `class Typeable a => Persistent a` adds a *constraint* that anything that is `Persistent` must also be `Typeable`. It is probably needed but it doesn't help you satisfy the constraint. You still need to produce `Typeable` instances one way or another (e,g. add `deriving (Typeable)` to all relevant `data` clauses).

Comment: @n.m thanks for explanation and feel free to make it answer so I can "accept" it! Also thank for clarifying that adding constraint to typeclass doesn't help :)

Comment: But why do you need this? In each particular instance, you *know* the type -- you just wrote it down in the instance declaration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

In `class Persistent a`, a doesn't have to represent a data type declaration. It's just a type. For example, one can add a `Persistent` instance for `Maybe Integer`.

```
instance Persistent (Maybe Integer) where ...
```

So it doesn't make much sense to talk about "adding a `deriving (Typeable)` clause to all `a`s that happen to be `Persistent`". One cannot say `data Maybe Integer deriving Typeable` or anything like that.

---

If you are absolutely sure that every `Persistent` thing *must* be `Typeable`, you may want to add a *constraint* to your `Persistent` class:

```
class Typeable a => Persistent a where ...
```

This however doesn't help you in any way with automatic derivation of `Typeable`. It just *requires* that for every `Persistent` instance there should be a `Typeable` instance, which you still have to produce yourself one way or another (e.g. by adding `deriving (Typeable)` to all relevant data types).

Comment: `Typeable` is perhaps a special example, since in modern GHCs, everything is implicitly a member of the `Typeable` class, and `deriving Typeable` is a no-op. Therefore, the superclass constraint is good enough and is effectively “free”, except for the runtime cost of passing the dictionaries around.